# Remove or replace numeric values in mixed data type

Tags: r

this seems like an easy question and I did some searches but cannot really find an obvious answer. I have a data frame with mixture of numeric values and characters:

```
df=data.frame(ID=c("S1","S2","S3","S4","S5"),
              V1=c("0.3","A","A","0.6","C"),
              V2=c("C","A","0.7","B","0.2"),
              V3=c("0.2","B","0.7","C","C"),stringsAsFactors=F)
tibble(df)

  ID    V1    V2    V3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 S1    0.3   C     0.2  
2 S2    A     A     B    
3 S3    A     0.7   0.7  
4 S4    0.6   B     C    
5 S5    C     0.2   C
```

Apparently they are all "character" type and what I want to achieve is to remove or replace all "numeric" elements in the data frame to NA so the ideal output would be:

```
  ID    V1    V2    V3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 S1    NA    C     NA  
2 S2    A     A     B    
3 S3    A     NA    NA  
4 S4    NA    B     C    
5 S5    C     NA    C 

OR

  ID    V1    V2    V3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 S1          C       
2 S2    A     A     B    
3 S3    A          
4 S4          B     C    
5 S5    C           C
```

Hope that makes sense. Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function num2na that uses `type.convert` then checks if it converted to numeric.  Vectorize(num2na) produces a function that can work on a vector and we apply that to each column turning the resulting list back into a data frame using replace. No packages are used.

```
num2na <- function(x) if (is.numeric(type.convert(x))) NA else x
replace(df, TRUE, lapply(df, Vectorize(num2na)))
```

giving:

```
  ID   V1   V2   V3
1 S1 <NA>    C <NA>
2 S2    A    A    B
3 S3    A <NA> <NA>
4 S4 <NA>    B    C
5 S5    C <NA>    C
```

Comment: `df[] = apply(df, c(1,2), num2na)` is slightly simpler

Comment: @Columbo, But it overwrites the input which, in general, is undesirable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the regex pattern `'^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?'` to find the values which are only numbers, then use `dplyr::across` to apply it to each column to replace any value that satisfies that pattern to `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(V1:V3, ~replace(.x, grepl('^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?', .x), NA)))

#  ID   V1   V2   V3
#1 S1 <NA>    C <NA>
#2 S2    A    A    B
#3 S3    A <NA> <NA>
#4 S4 <NA>    B    C
#5 S5    C <NA>    C
```

Or with `lapply` in base R :

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) replace(x, grepl('^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?', x), NA))
```

Comment: Thanks but the other answer works a little better for me. I appreciate the help!